# Using PHP and Ajax to open gallery images on same page

Tags: php, ajax

PHP and AJAX Code:

```
<div id = "galleryContainer"></div>
```

```
var linkArray = document.getElementByTagName('a');

for (var i = 0; i > linkArray.length; i++)
{
    if (linkArray[i].getAttribute('class') == 'myLinks')
    {
        linkArray[i].onclick = function ()
        {
            var url = (this.href);

            var xmlhttp;

            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
            {
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest ();
            }
            else
            {
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject ("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }

            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
            {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
                {
                    document.getElementById ("galleryContainer").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            }

            xmlhttp.open ("GET", "stubs/storage.php?theurl="+url, true);
            xmlhttp.send()

            return (false);

        }
    }
}
```

Currently I'm testing this on localhost, and what happens is I have links displayed in my HTML. When clicked, they open correctly, however the URL changes to the actual location of the image

```
http://localhost/images/gallery/image-name.extension.
```

And in order to go back to the page, you literally have to hit the back button. I'm trying to make it so that the links display the picture directly underneath where the HTML links are present.

I'm trying to call upon another file called storage.php, however it doesn't seem to working. I tried using alerts and even used another file, however it just won't open it. So far I don't believe there's a problem with my linking the wrong location of the file, but rather a problem with me calling the file. I'm using a fair bit of code from a W3 example.

As usual, I did do my research, and tried to follow other stackoverflow examples where people wanted to open something in a new window and tried to reverse-engineer it into my code, however it didn't work. I'm fairly new to Ajax, and so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: use lightbox to click on image url

Comment: don't reinvent the wheel. Use lightbox, fancybox etc... ...Just do a search on google.

Comment: Aren't both lightbox and fancybox made using jquery? I'd rather not use Jquery if I don't have to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need only one image on the page. I recommend making galleryContainer an image:

```
<img src="" id="galleryContainer" />
```

Using this as JS:

```
for (var i = 0; i > linkArray.length; i++)
{
    if (linkArray[i].getAttribute('class') == 'myLinks')
    {
        linkArray[i].onclick = function ()
        {
            var url = (this.href);

            document.getElementById('galleryContainer').src = url;
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

The image will reload every time it's source is changed, and I think that achieves the effect you are trying to reach.

That said, as people mentioned in the comments [fancybox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#examples) is probably more likely to be what you are trying to achieve, so it may be worth investigating.

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked. The problem was that I was using getElementByTag whereas I was supposed to be using getElementsByTag.

I also used your method instead of what I was using initially as its very minimalist and indeed what I was going for.